# Flask generic exception handler unable to catch 405 error

Tags: python, flask

I've created an exception handler according to [this piece of documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#generic-exception-handlers):

```
import json

from flask import Blueprint, abort, current_app, jsonify, make_response, request
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

import pmo.service as pmo

ops = Blueprint("ops", __name__)


@ops.route("/today", methods=["GET"])
def get_today():
    current_app.logger.info("Getting an entry for 'today'")
    try:
        return jsonify(pmo.get_today_entry())
    except IndexError:
        abort(404, "No entry for today")


@ops.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    # pass through HTTP errors as json
    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        response = e.get_response()
        payload = json.dumps({
            "code": e.code,
            "name": e.name,
            "description": e.description,
        })
        response.data = f"{payload}\n"
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        return make_response(response, e.code)

    # now handle non-HTTP exceptions only
    response_body = {"code": 500, "message": "unhandled exception occurred", "details": str(e)}
    return make_response(response_body, 500)
```

I decided to use this approach because I'm developing a REST api and wanted to get rid of any html responses. Still when I issue a POST request in order to trigger a 405 error it is being returned as html document and not json:

```
❯ curl -X POST localhost:5000/today

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

While GET request is handled as expected:

```
❯ curl localhost:5000/today

{"code": 404, "name": "Not Found", "description": "No entry for a given day"}
```

In fact the error handler is not being invoked on 405, I've verified that with a debugger.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried putting that error handler on the app instead of the blueprint? I've never seen error handlers on blueprints before.

Comment: Indeed @KenKinder this was the issue - I had to place that error handler in my app's entrypoint in order for it to catch 405 Method Not Allowed error as well. Many thanks!

Comment: @KenKinder can you add that as an Answer? excellent!

Comment: @szmktk added an answer (cc @ti7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error handler needs to be on the app object, not the blueprint. Try:

```py
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    ...
```

Other than that, I don't see anything problematic about your code.

Answer (score 1):

As @KenKinder kindly pointed out in the comment the problem was in the placement of the generic exception handler. After moving it to application's entrypoint it started to work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered, it needs to go on the `@app` but some further details:

> In Modular Applications with Blueprints, most error handlers will work as expected. However, there is a caveat concerning handlers for 404 and 405 exceptions.

> This is because the blueprint does not “own” a certain URL space, so the application instance has no way of knowing which blueprint error handler it should run if given an invalid URL.

Documentation for this: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/errorhandling/#blueprint-error-handlers